# How to find common substrings in two strings

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have been struggling with a problem for the last 2 days and was wondering if the community could help out. I have a NSString of numbers and I need to compare how many numbers match the amount of numbers in another string.

Example:

```
     String 1: 14523 25623 651 88

     String 2: 9123 88 14523 333
```

Based on these 2 strings, we can see that they both contain "88" and "14523". So there are 2 matches. I don't know how to figure out this comparison via code.

I have thought of simply having a substring to break up string 1 and compare each value to string 2 but this is very inefficient. I believe there is a better way.

Can anyone offer any advice? An example would be extremely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This seems like the kind of question any coder would likely to be asked in a job interview.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Good thing I'm still learning:)

Comment: all the answers coming in *assume* that the numbers are separated by spaces.  Is that going to be the case with the numbers in your string?  In other words, will there always be spaces between the numbers you're looking for... or maybe not?  E.G. "`145232562365188`", where there might be a "`14523`" in the other string of "`91238814523333`"

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Yes there will always be a space. Out of curiosity (and perhaps for those having this problem), how would this be done if you could not separate the strings based on the space?

Comment: I'd rather save that for another question, or homework, since I still think it's the kind of question you (or any other good coder) is going to eventually get asked in some job interview down the road.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Fair enough

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a set of substrings for each string. Then do an intersection of the two sets to find the common substrings.

```
NSString *string1 = @"14523 25623 651 88";
NSString *string2 = @"9123 88 14523 333";
NSSet *setA = [NSSet setWithArray:[string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
NSSet *setB = [NSSet setWithArray:[string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
NSMutableSet *common = [setA mutableCopy];
[common intersectSet:setB];
NSLog(@"common substrings = %@", common);
```

Comment: Thank you for willing to provide an example!

Comment: That is some beautiful code and works properly. Thank you so much! Will accept

Answer (score 3):

```
    NSString *str1 = @"14523 25623 651 88";
    NSString *str2 = @"9123 88 14523 333";
    NSArray *chunks = [str1 componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
    NSArray *chunks2 = [str2 componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
    NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:chunks];
    [intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:chunks2]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [intersection allObjects]);
```

Comment: yeah! :D Even I was surprised looking at the other answer!

Comment: But I guess this is the path of least resistance in Obj-C

Comment: @Neo Thanks for the answer Neo. Your code works as well and is similar to maddy but they posted first. Will upvote though!

Answer (score 0):

You create two array:

First array with method componentsSeparatedByString with string one.

Second array with method componentsSeparatedByString with string two.

Now, add elemnt from second array to first array, add only if first array doesnt contain this element.